# Failed to append image to next matched class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append an image to another div where is nearest to the link that clicked. **I only want to append the image to the next matched class , not all of it**

this is how my html look like

```
<div id="container">

<div class="product">
<div class="link_wrap"><a class="expand">link 1</a></div>
<div class="flyer"></div>
</div

<div class="product">
<div class="link_wrap"><a class="expand">link 2</a></div>
<div class="flyer"></div>
</div

<div class="product">
<div class="link_wrap"><a class="expand">link 3</a></div>
<div class="flyer"></div>
</div

</div>
```

This is my js

```
$("#container").on("click",".expand",{foo: "hello"}, expandHandler);

function expandHandler(event) {
alert('clicked');
$(this).closest("div.flyer").append("<b>Hey!</b>");
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgXyD/7/)

All my content is dynamically generated so i forced to use on().The function are probably called . I have tried replace closest with children and next but with no luck i can't get it to work. I appreciate any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to select the div next to the parent of the clicked `a` element :

```
$(this).parent().next("div.flyer").append("<b>Hey!</b>");
```

In order to be more reliable when the HTML changes, you might also want to select the `div.flier` element in the same `div.product` :

```
$(this).closest('.product').find(".flyer").append("<b>Hey!</b>");
```

Comment: Thanks its Worked! i don't know i'm this close to the answer , just one more question , am i doing thing right , i actually storing <img> path in <a> and then call it like this

Comment: @LeonArmstrong I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry , I am inserting img like
$(this).closest('.product').find(".flyer").append("<img src='imagepath' />");
Am i doing thing right , because i can't find any question that close to this

Comment: This is one of the many correct ways. There's no real problem here.